# Is there a way to add a value on an axis where the curve of the graph hits it?

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

Okay so I got a bit of code here plotting for a population dynamics graph, and I would love to have a certain value written at each "end" of the curve, on the x and y axis, as seen here : https://images.ecosia.org/EIQKP81uukSNIVwegG9q5w1xhmM=/0x390/smart/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.webpages.uidaho.edu%2Fwlf448%2Fimages%2Fstableb.gif

I tried to remove the axis numbers first because I don't need them, but the real issue here is that I have a bucket load of these graphs (there's a looped version of the code but I won't show it here to keep it simple) and I'd like to have these values added automatically.

```
### Outcome study with isoclines

#Clearing workspace
rm(list=ls())
graphics.off()

#plot setup
#par(mfrow=c(2,2))

#Parameters
lambda1<- 3.2
lambda2<- 3
alphs <- matrix(c(0.005, 0.005, 0.0045, 0.004), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

#Plotting isoclines
plot(0,0,type="l",xlab='N1',ylab='N2',col='blue',xlim =c(0,470),
     ylim = c(0,750))
abline(a=((lambda1-1)/alphs[1,2]),b=(- alphs[1,1]/alphs[1,2]),col='blue')
abline(a=((lambda2-1)/alphs[2,2]),b=(- alphs[2,1]/alphs[2,2]),col='green')

legend("topright", legend = c("Species 1", "Species 2"),lty = 1, 
       col = c("blue", "green"), bty = "n")

arrows(x0 = 300, y0 = 600, x1 = 270, y1 = 600, length = 0.06,col="blue")
arrows(x0 = 300, y0 = 600, x1 = 300, y1 = 510, length = 0.06, col="green")
arrows(x0 = 50, y0 = 100, x1 = 80, y1 = 100, length = 0.06,col="blue")
arrows(x0 = 50, y0 = 100, x1 = 50, y1 = 190, length = 0.06, col="green")
```

I don't know what to expect honestly, but there must be a way to do it, right ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can calculate the location where you want to add the text, you can use the `axis()` function to add it.  For example, to put the values on the y axis,
you want them at the place where x is equal to `par("usr")[1]`.  This code does that:

```
x <- par("usr")[1]
a <- c(((lambda1-1)/alphs[1,2]), ((lambda2-1)/alphs[2,2]))
b <- c((- alphs[1,1]/alphs[1,2]), (- alphs[2,1]/alphs[2,2]))
y <- a + b*x
axis(2, at = y, labels = expression(K[2], K[1]/a[2,1]), tick = FALSE, line = -1)
```

I think the labels aren't quite right, since `x` is negative, not zero; you can add `xaxs = "i"` to your plot call to avoid this.  You can move them in or out from the graph by changing the value of `line` in the `axis()` call.  With the `plot` change and the code above, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes ! this is typically what I was looking for. Thank you, this will look very good (:
I looked up at the axis function a little bit before but I didn't know how to use it.